# How to use Tensorboard to determine important features?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a binary classifier model which is built using the estimator api.  This model has around 300 features and one label.  I am using a one hidden layer model with 175 neurons.

I run the model with 5000 training steps.  Before the split into training, test and validation sets I have 278 instances of one class and 178 of the second class.  Its not perfectly balanced.

With that said, I get an accuracy of 0.984.

So, I am trying to interpret the results of the histogram to see if I can use that to determine which features are more important than others.  Here are some pictures from the histogram tab.

[image: hidden_layer_0 activation]

Here is the screenshot of the logits.

[image: logits activation]

Answer (score 1):

Based on those screenshots, it looks like those histograms are for the activation values from both your hidden layer and your logits. I don't believe that will give you any indication as to how your features are influencing the model output, because *those histograms are simply computing the distribution of output values for those graph operations*.

In general, I think Tensorboard is much more suited for *monitoring* rather than *analysis*, as the primary goal of Tensorboard is to [make it easier to understand, debug, and optimize TensorFlow programs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard).

That being said, the Tensorflow team built a tool called [Tensorflow Model Analysis](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-analysis) (**TFMA**), which looks like it's perfectly suited for what you're trying to do:

[image: Gif of example TFMA use as seen in its README]

If you're using the estimator API already, you should be able to adapt your code to use TFMA without a lot of changes needed. The [getting started guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/model_analysis/get_started) may be a good starting point!

Comment: If you really want to use Tensorboard for this, you could try creating a custom metric for your estimator such as [tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_covariance](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/streaming_covariance?hl=en), passing your features as the `predictions` argument and your logits activation as the `labels` argument. Seems hacky, and I've never tried it, but just a thought :)